Why are UK General Elections near the start of a month?
The dates of the most recent UK General Elections were:

Thu 4 Jul 2024
Thu 12 Dec 2019
Thu 8 Jun 2017
Thu 7 May 2015
Thu 6 May 2010
Thu 5 May 2005
Thu 7 Jun 2001
Thu 1 May 1997
Thu 9 Apr 1992
Thu 11 Jun 1987
Thu 9 Jun 1983
Thu 3 May 1979
Thu 10 Oct 1974
Thu 28 Feb 1974
Thu 18 Jun 1970
Thu 31 Mar 1966

It is clear that a summer day --- when it is daylight for many hours --- is preferred. We also see that, from Oct 1974 onwards, the dates are near the beginning of a month. We have to go all the way back to Feb 1974 to see a date later than the 12th of any month. This is true no matter the party of the Prime Minister choosing the date, and no matter which party is expected to win.
Granted, the timing of the 2015 General Election accorded with the Fixed-term Parliaments Act 2011. Per this Act, General Elections are "automatically scheduled for the first Thursday in May of the fifth year after the previous general election, or the fourth year if the date of the previous election was before the first Thursday in May" [Wiki]. But then the 2017 and 2019 General Elections were called early, so the aforementioned default date doesn't explain the actual dates chosen. And that Act was repealed in 2022 anyway.
Question: Why do UK Prime Ministers choose a day near the beginning of a month for a General Election?
This is not about the convention to choose a Thursday, a convention very rarely broken.

1964 was 15 October.

2024 was held earlier in July because the English summer holidays traditionally start in mid-July, and people (including possibly candidates) would be out of the country.

I think a lot of this can be attributed to the Representation of the People Act 1983, which set the annual date of local elections as 'the first Thursday in May' by statute. General elections are often held alongside local elections to, amongst other reasons, increase turnout and save money. This accounts for the dates of the five general elections between 1997-2015 elections (the 2001 election was delayed by a month due to foot-and-mouth). The 1979 election was also held at the same time as the local elections of that year, although this was prior to the Act, and unusual at the time.
Success in the local elections may also buoy Prime Ministers into calling a snap election, which is consequently held the requisite four weeks after dissolving Parliament - at the beginning of June. This helps account for the 1983 and 1987 elections.

Historically, certain days have been avoided because they're known to depress turnout; In particular, politicians have been keen not to schedule elections on a Friday because it was traditionally payday for people who were paid weekly.
For the same reason, elections tend to be held earlier in the month, basically as far from the month-end payday for workers who get their pay monthly, and hence will have more money in their pockets and more distractions from voting.

Is payday is at the end of a month, then surely such workers are likely to have more money in their pockets early in the (following) month, than they are later in the month?  (Maybe politicians want workers to feel rich and confident and positive when they vote?)

@gidds - Most people have spent the bulk of their pay (on their essentials) by the second week of the month. Payday and shortly afterwards is when you feel flush with money. After a few days reality sets back in

UK elections are always on a Thursday.   Always, unless there is some overwhelmingly good reason to schedule it otherwise (such as the Hamilton by-election of 31 May 1978.  which was held on a Wednesday to avoid clashing with the opening game of the World Cup)

i was wondering about why earlier, when conservatives were having some time to think about another strategy?

Rather than "more distractions from voting", surely it makes more sense to assume "less reason to be dissatisfied with one's circumstances". The current government get to call the date, and incumbents are always susceptible to knee-jerk protest votes, obviously. The incumbent loses less votes to general disaffection by going for the first week or two when the monthly-paid get paid. And even the "4-weekly paid" have outgoings based on calendar months, so their bank balances have comparable cycles.

@FumbleFingers - Most people in the UK have their essential payments timed to leave their accounts shortly after their pay lands; rent, utilities, etc.

Obviously. But when you skim though daily bank balances on paper or online, you tend to assess "stability" on the basis of monthly start balance being relatively stable. And some outgoings (pub on Friday night) are weekly, which means the finances might become less stable nearer the end of the month, regardless of weekly, monthly, or fwaply income, or what day of the month your ISP provider bills you.

@FumbleFingers - The point is that you're most likely to feel flush immediately after payday, regardless of how shit your actual finances are :-)

Indeed. And it occurs to me that my "reasoning / rationale" doesn't even have to be true. It just has to be the case that most PM's (and or their advisors) think it might be true. Regardless of whether the current government is Labour or Conservative, the incumbent benefits from voters who are less worried about their current balance. Which either is or could be more likely at the beginning of the month.
